# how does gvim picks the default font

Tags: vim, fonts

I understand that I can use `:set guifont?` to find the current guifont (IF it has been set), and I can use `:set guifont=*< font >*` to set the guifont. However, in my case, **I didn't set guifont anywhere in .vimrc or .gvimrc**. When I run `:set guifont?`, it simply returns an empty string.

```
guifont=
```

I want to know where/how exactly gvim picks the default font.

Comment: Did you add the `:set guifont` value?